# How to set a Foreign Key based on multiple column with django-import-export?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-import-export

There's a model defining which combination of department/position needs what types of training. Another model shows employees with all related information. All the data comes from xlsx file via django-import-export. The problem is that I can't figure out how to set a foreign key in employees model based on the unique combination of department and position rows, so each employee gets the training field value accordingly. I've tried this solution but it didn't work (or maybe I did something wrong): https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/375
I'm new to programming and this is my first project. Hope some of you can help.
Here is my model defining training for each combination of department/position:

```
class TrainingMatrix(models.Model):
department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False, null=True)
position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False, null=True)
training = models.ManyToManyField(Training)
```

Here is the Employee model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
badge = models.CharField(max_length=15, primary_key=True, unique=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
department = models.ForeignKey(TrainingMatrix, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,related_name='department_name')
position = models.ForeignKey(TrainingMatrix, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,related_name='position_title')
training = models.ForeignKey(TrainingMatrix, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

And the xlsx file's column titles I import:
badge, name, position, department

Comment: You wouldn't normally have 3 FKs to the same table in Employee.  Instead have 1 FK in Employee which points to a reference in TrainingMatrix.  Also the 'department' and 'position' references in Employee probably should be references to Department and Position.  For import, I guess you would override the `init_instance()` method to have some kind of lookup / logic to find and then assign the correct TrainingMatrix to Employee.training.  A tricky problem for your first project, but hopefully this helps you on the right lines.

Comment: @MatthewHegarty thanks a lot for having a look at my question! Yeah, I also thought it was a silly idea to have 3 FK pointing to the same model. So I've changed it and now position and department fields of Employee point to Position and Department models respectively. Regarding init_instance(), I've tried to find some working example on the net but couldn't find any. Maybe you could help me understand how it's usually written. Here's what I've came up for now but of course it doesn't work:

Comment: def init_instance(self, row, *args, **kwargs):
        print ("I'm working")
        for traininig in TrainingMatrix.objects.all():
            if self.department == training.department and self.position == training.position:
                self.training = training.id
                self.training.save()
                return instance

Comment: There isn't a usual way for implementing init_instance() - it's just a hook you can use to customise the import logic.  This might be where you can implement the business logic for setting the training field.  Try to set breakpoints in the code, and then step through so that you can figure out (and understand) what's going on.  Work it all out on paper first (i.e. the rules for assigning training).  If you take the time to plan and understand everything first it saves time in the long run.  Sorry I cannot provide direct help, but hopefully this puts you on the right track.